# Tag autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits, autocomplete

At the moment, the tag autocompletion doesn't work. Below is an example for inline tag edits, but the problem is also present on 'full' edit pages (like the one I'm typing this question in). Suggested tags do work, however.

[image]

I'm seeing a 500 Internal Server Error in my browser console, and it seems to be a network-wide problem. Tested with the latest Firefox and Safari on macOS.

Comment: Works OK here (same OS and browsers plus Chrome)

Comment: Right, seems to be a temporary glitch then. I can no longer reproduce it either.

Comment: Nor can I.  I guess it's fixed :-X

Comment: c........................a.............n...................y...................o....................u.................r.................................................g......................I.........................f..............................................b........................e.........................................................a.......................n.....................y.............................s...........................l.........................o...........................w...........................e................................r................................?

Comment: @Won't yeah, I noticed that too. I'm not sure what happened; I regularly make GIF screencasts via QuickTime and an ffpmeg / gifsicle script, but this time it refuses to make anything but a SlowTime version.

Comment: b....................o....................o.....................:.......................(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was me, sorry - simply fumbled some code, and it slipped through. It was noticed immediately after the deploy, and fixed in under half an hour. It should now work everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a comment but I wanted to add some additional details with a screenshot.  I was just about to report this same issue.  Asking a question on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com and I can't add autocompleted tags:

Screenshot of Chrome dev tools:

[image]

Headers:

[image]

[image]